# Get separated data from miltiple lines with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have this data lines:

```
City:  London
Email:  main@email.com

Name:    Mr.Test
Emails:  email1@mail.com
      email2@mail.com
invalid-email-too
```

with this code:

```
if(preg_match('/\nEmails: (.*).\n/s', $query, $matches)) {
    return $matches[1];
}
```

I got string result like this:

```
email1@mail.com
          email2@mail.com
```

but I need it as already separated result as array.
And then best solution to get array result with "Email:" and "Emails:" too.
How to do it with one regex please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~(?:\G(?!\A)|^Emails:)\s*\K\S+@\S+\.\S+~m'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DEqRuN/1)

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|^Emails:)` - `Emails:` at the start of a line (`^Emails:`, note that `m` modifier makes `^` match both the start of a string and all line start positions) or the end of the previous match (`\G(?!\A)`)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all the text matched so far from the whole match buffer
- `\S+@\S+\.\S+` - an email-like pattern: 1+ non-whitespaces, `@`, 1+ non-whitespaces, `.` and again 1+ non-whitespaces.

[PHP usage](https://ideone.com/KtP8un):

```
if (preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!\A)|^Emails:)\s*\K\S+@\S+\.\S+~m', $s, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]); // => Array ( [0] => email1@mail.com [1] => email2@mail.com ) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach, which however seems to work well, at least for your sample data.  It just goes after email addresses wherever they might appear:

```
$input = "City:  London\nEmail:  main@email.com\n\nName:    Mr.Test\nEmails:  email1@mail.com\n      email2@mail.com";
preg_match_all ("/\b\w+@[^.]+\.\w+\b/U", $input, $array);
print_r($array[0]);

Array
(
    [0] => main@email.com
    [1] => email1@mail.com
    [2] => email2@mail.com
)
```

### Demo

Where this approach would go wrong is if there could be email addresses appearing in your text which are *not* prefaced by an `Emails:` header.  In that case, this answer would give false matches.

Comment: @D.Schaller Yes, but do we have any data right now which suggests that email addresses could appear anywhere else?  I prefer a simple solution if it can work.

Comment: When emails are in wrong format without @ or dot then it doesn`t work. It must return all emails. Valid or wrong.

Comment: @step Can you show some examples of bad emails?  Note that it's kind of hard to guess what pattern to use.  Even existing email regex are geared towards _valid_ emails, and not invalid ones.

Comment: Edited content.